# Howler.JS + Angular - path for playing sound file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, audio, howler.js

I'm trying to **play mp3** file in cordova + ionic hybrid app.

Sound is stored in:

```
www/sounds/dubstep/sound.mp3
```

And i'm trying to play file from service placed in `/www/scripts/services/global.js` using following code:

```
var sound = new Howl({
     src: ['sounds/dubstep/sound.mp3'],
     onend: function() {
         console.log('Finished!');
     },
     onloaderror: function() {
        console.log('Error!');
    },
});

sound.play();
```

But it is always throwing `onloaderror`.

How I should set path in right way?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version are you using? Upcoming 2 or the latest stable version?

Comment: Do you know if Cordova supports mp3? I've never tested it, but I"ve used node-webkit, which doesn't support mp3 because of the proprietary nature.

Comment: Can you check the network tab to verify if there is a 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to github documentation you should be using `urls` instead of `src`:

```
var sound = new Howl({
    urls: ['sounds/dubstep/sound.mp3'],
    onend: function() {
        console.log('Finished!');
    },
    onloaderror: function() {
        console.log('Error!');
    },
});
```

Src: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/

Comment: If they are using the upcoming 2.0 release, then `src` is correct.